# How can I plot a stacked graph in Python?

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, stacked-chart

```
Group_1= {60: 2, 65: 2}
Group_2= {5: 2, 10: 2}
Group_3= {7: 2, 64: 2}
Group_4= {14: 2}
```

These are the 4 different dictionaries, and my aim is to plot a stacked graph on which

- x-axis = Group Numbers
- y-axis = values of the dictionaries only.

I do not want keys in the graph,
and `Group_4` has the only single key and value as a data.
I've also attached the image.

I am getting an error:

> ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape.

Comment: please provide your full code and a mockup of the expected graph for clarity

Answer (score 1):

One option using `matplotlib` bar plot.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create a single structure to hold your groups. Could work with a list as well.
groups = {"1": G1.values(), "2": G2.values(), "3": G3.values(), "4": G4.values()}

for x, values in groups.items():
    bottom = 0
    for value in values:
        plt.bar(x, value, bottom=bottom)
        bottom += value
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One option using [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas):

```
import pandas as pd

groups = {1: Group_1, 2: Group_2, 3: Group_3, 4: Group_4}

pd.DataFrame.from_dict(groups, orient='index').plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

Output:

[image]

Variant:

```
(pd.DataFrame.from_dict({k: list(d.values())
                         for k, d in groups.items()},
                         orient='index')
   .plot.bar(stacked=True, legend=False)
)
```

Output:

[image]